# jQuery - String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to capitalize the very first letter of `quote`. Do I need to capitalize the first letter before or after I add the `<blockquote>` and `<q>`tags, virtually?

I just can't seem to get it figured out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("span").each(function() {

      var quote = $(this).text();   
      quote.charAt(0).toUpperCase + quote.slice(1);     
      $(this).parent().after("<blockquote><q>" + quote + "</q></blockquote>");          
  });

  $("blockquote").css({ 
    "font-weight":"bold", 
    "font-size" : "120%",
    "border-top":"solid 1px",
    "border-bottom":"solid 1px",
    "margin":"30px",
    "padding":"15px",
    "border-color":"grey"
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd also do it with css, but probably why you're not seeing a difference is because you aren't updating what 'quote' is. Try quote = quote.charAt...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [CSS text-transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)? Check out the following...

```
span {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6wwvuom/) - demo

Comment: That works beautifully! I totally forgot you can do this with using CSS. That makes it so much simpler. Thank you, scniro!